# Are questions about platforms for collaboration and distribution on topic?

Tags: discussion

I've been using Logic Pro X for a while and uploading some of my pieces to Splice.com and SoundCloud.com for sharing and collaboration. So, I wonder whether questions related to how those platforms work are on topic.

**Update**

For instance, in SoundCloud I've updated the link or web address of some of my songs, so that the link I've been sharing points to the lates version.

However, it seems that places where I've shared those songs still play the old version of the song, even when the link has changed.

Something like this:

http://SoundCloud.com/user/song-1 becomes http://SoundCloud.com/user/song-1a
http://SoundCloud.com/user/song-1 is the new version

When I play what it's supposed to be the new song-1 shared in a tweet, I still get the old version song-1a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They definitely can be on topic, however have a good read of the topics under our help tab at the top to help guide you, however some questions on those platforms may be off topic here (and on topic on SO, for example, if they are really about programming.)

This might be easier to give you a definite answer if you have some examples.

Comment: I see... I added a description with the specific problem I have.

Comment: Okay - that is not on topic here then. That's very much a question about a particular web application and how it handles version control, I guess.

Comment: I'll try SE Web Applications then, thanks a lot.